# How do I handle empty cells while reading Excel with org.jxls in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, jxls

I am using the org.jxls library in a Spring Boot project to read an Excel file. The reading process is working fine, but when it encounters an empty cell, it throws an org.jxls.reader.XLSDataReadException exception. I would like to skip reading the empty cell and continue with the next cell.

Here is my XML configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<workbook>
    <worksheet name="Sheet1">
        <section startRow="0" endRow="0" />
        <loop startRow="1" endRow="1" items="estimations" var="estimation"
            varType="com.osi.exceljxls.entities.Estimation">
            <section startRow="1" endRow="1">
                <mapping row="1" col="0">estimation.role</mapping>
                <mapping row="1" col="1">estimation.noOfResources</mapping>
                <mapping row="1" col="3">estimation.projectLocation</mapping>
                <!-- Other mappings -->
                <!-- ... -->
                <cellcheck offset="0" evaluator="org.jxls.common.cell.reader.IsEmptyCellCheck" />
            </section>
            <loopbreakcondition>
                <rowcheck offset="0">
                    <cellcheck offset="0" />
                </rowcheck>
            </loopbreakcondition>
        </loop>
      </worksheet>
  </workbook>
```

I have already tried adding the `<cellcheck />` tag as shown above, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I also considered handling the exception, but I am unsure how to proceed in that case.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to skip reading empty cells or how to handle the XLSDataReadException when an empty cell is encountered. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. In my service class, I need to add this line of code before reading the excel to avoid the `org.jxls.reader.XLSDataReadException` exception: `ReaderConfig.getInstance().setSkipErrors(true);`. With this adjustment, the code will read the empty cell and return 0 without any issues.